# ¿Es posible poner una linea vertical que va de llave a llave como la de Visual Studio en eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, formato

En visual Studio, te pone una linea vertical discontinua en los metodos, que van desde la llave que abre el metodo, hasta la llave que cierra.

Es posile poner esto en eclipse?

la imagen a continuación, muestra lo que quiero

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

muchas gracias!!

Comment: Creo que no, aunque no estoy del todo seguro. Lo que sí tienes en eclipse es si haces doble click dentro de la llave te marca todo el bloque. Y por supuesto se marcan las llaves si sitúas el cursor.

Comment: muchas gracias!!